# derivate is based on addition, is there a muliplication analogon?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, error-propagation, multiplicative-function

like

$$
\operatorname{f^o}(x) = \lim_{h\to 1} \frac{f(x*h)}{f(x)}
$$

$$
\operatorname{f}(x)=e^x  
$$

$$
\operatorname{f^o}(x) = \lim_{h \to 1} e^{x*h}/e^{x} = \lim_{h\to 1} e^{x*h-x}=e^0=1
$$

does it have a name and some theories behind it?
if not why is this alt-derivative not used?

it would be nice if someone can point me in the right direction since I'm unsure what to search for without a name.

the application is if this could be used on a special machine learning approach instead of a gradient descent based on normal derives.

I'm only interested in purely positive functions unequal zero to apply this on

edit the correct formular:
from @B.Martin book reference in the comments:

https://books.google.com.au/books?id=_Eg7p3UXJjUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Bigeometric+Calculus:+A+System+With+a+Scale-free+Derivative%E2%80%8E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ4eek-_buAhVIwjgGHc_wCWYQ6AEwAHoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=Bigeometric%20Calculus%3A%20A%20System%20With%20a%20Scale-free%20Derivative%E2%80%8E&f=false

$$
lim_{x\to a} \frac{\operatorname{f}(x)}{\operatorname{f}(a)}^{\frac{1}{ln(x)-ln(a)}}
$$

Comment: The idea behind the derivative is to find the best linear approximation of $f$ at a point $a$, I don't get where you're trying to go with this.

Comment: Also notice, that as soon as your function $f$ is continuous your 'alt-derivative' will always equal 1 for all $x$. So for continuous functions this is not interesting from the get go.

Comment: In addition to not knowing why you are interested in this construction, I'm not quite sure why this wouldn't always just equal $1$ in nearly every circumstance.  $\lim\limits_{h\to 1}\frac{f(x\cdot h)}{f(x)} = 1$

Comment: @simone i expanded on the description johnnyb noam yeah thats allways one you are right

Comment: @PhilippZiehe I don't think this can have any meaningful application, try your definition on any continuous function.

Comment: This may be of interest https://books.google.com.au/books?id=_Eg7p3UXJjUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Bigeometric+Calculus:+A+System+With+a+Scale-free+Derivative%E2%80%8E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ4eek-_buAhVIwjgGHc_wCWYQ6AEwAHoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=Bigeometric%20Calculus%3A%20A%20System%20With%20a%20Scale-free%20Derivative%E2%80%8E&f=false

Comment: thx @B.Martin that seems to answer the question eactly

Answer (score 1):

wrong approach, thanks for the comments was stuck on my idea there :)